# How to mock node-cron job in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have a node application typescript based where I am running a cron job. It is being called when the server starts.

I am writting UT's for this file but I am unable to mock the node-cron module. Any leads will be very helpful.

```js
import { Log, LoggerInterface } from '@emileap/node-logger';
import { RetryKafkaConsumerGroup } from '../lib/kafka';
import * as Cron from 'node-cron';
import { env } from '../env';
import { mask } from '../env/helpers';
import { SubscriberStatus, getSubscriberByStatus } from '../lib/utils';

export class SubscriberRetryCronLoader {
        public brokenSubscribers: {[key: string]: any };
        public cronJob: any;
    constructor(
        @Log(__filename) private log: LoggerInterface
    ) {}

    public async retryBrokenSubscribers(): Promise<any | undefined> {
        try {
            const subscribers = await getSubscriberByStatus(SubscriberStatus.CircuitBroken);
            this.brokenSubscribers = {};
            this.log.info(`No of broken subscribers found retry cron loader: ${subscribers.length}`);
            subscribers.forEach((subscriber) => {
                const { subscriberId, callbackUrl, callbackMethod, types, updatedAt, financialId, channelId } = subscriber;
                const cgConfig = {
                    id: `${subscriberId}$${updatedAt}`,
                    groupId: `${env.kafka.consumerGroupPrefix}${subscriberId}`,
                    topics: types,
                    subscriberId,
                    financialId,
                    channelId,
                    callbackUrl,
                    callbackMethod,
                };

                this.log.info(`Retrying broken subscriber: ${mask(cgConfig.subscriberId)}$${updatedAt}`);
                this.brokenSubscribers[cgConfig.id] = new RetryKafkaConsumerGroup(cgConfig);
            });
        } catch (error: any) {
            this.log.error('Failure while retrying broken subscribers', error);
        }
    }

    public async startCronProcess(): Promise<any | undefined> {
        this.cronJob = Cron.schedule('* * * * *', this.retryBrokenSubscribers.bind(this));
        await this.retryBrokenSubscribers();
    }

    public destroyCronJob(): any {
        this.cronJob.destroy();
    }
}
```

I have tried something like this :-

```js
import * as Cron from 'node-cron';
import { SubscriberRetryCronLoader } from '../../../src/Crons/subscriberRetryCronLoader';
import { LogMock } from '../mocks';

describe('Retry cron loader', () => {
    let subscriberRetryCronLoader: SubscriberRetryCronLoader;
    let mockLog;
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
        mockLog = new LogMock();
        subscriberRetryCronLoader = new SubscriberRetryCronLoader(mockLog);
        jest.mock('node-cron', () => {
            return {
              schedule: jest.fn(),
            };
        });
    });

    it('should run the cron', async () => {
        Cron.schedule.mockImplementationOnce(async (frequency, callback) => await callback());
    });
});
```

But I am getting below error

```js
FAIL  test/unit/crons/subscriberRetryCronLoader.test.ts (5.931 s)
  Retry cron loader
    × should run the cron (7 ms)

  ● Retry cron loader › should run the cron

    TypeError: Cron.schedule.mockImplementationOnce is not a function

      19 |     });
      20 |
    > 21 |     it('should run the cron', async () => {
         |                       ^
      22 |         Cron.schedule.mockImplementationOnce(async (frequency, callback) => await callback());

      at test/unit/crons/subscriberRetryCronLoader.test.ts:21:23
      at node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:169:75
      at Object.__awaiter (node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:165:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/unit/crons/subscriberRetryCronLoader.test.ts:20:45)
```

Kindly let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think modules should be mocked at top level:

```js
import * as Cron from 'node-cron';

jest.mock('node-cron', () => {
  return {
    schedule: jest.fn(),
  };
});

describe('...', () => {
  // ... setup ...
  test('...', () => {
    jest.mocked(Cron).schedule.mockImplementationOnce((schedule, func) => {
      if (typeof func === 'function') {
        func(new Date());
      }
      return {} as unknown as any // TODO: implement ScheduledTask return
    });
    // call your code which calls Cron.schedule
  });
});
```